# animate recyclerview to outside

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I want to animate a `recyclerview` item to outside(sibling) of the `recyclerview`. I tried many different animation code and libraries but nothing happened. My problem is to animate a row of `recyclerview` to a `linearlayout` outside(sibling) of recyclerview.
see attached picture.

[image: Attachment]

My Main Layout flow is:

```
ConstraintLayout
--LinearLayout
----View (empty)
--Recyclerview
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `Shared element transition` built-in from Android (search for more tutorial about this keyword)

It doesn't support the transition from within 1 view. But you can use Fragment to achieve the same result. Your activity will be like this:

> ConstraintLayout (Activity)
>
> --FrameLayout (container for the Fragment)
>
> --Recyclerview

The Fragment contains the layout of your item's destination view.

I imagine the flow can be like this:

- User taps on an item in RecyclerView in Activity
- Replace new fragment to the container with defined data for shared element transition

https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb